# import excel file which has various languages into mysql database

Tags: mysql, excel

I am trying to import excel file which has various languages such as Russian, French, Japanese, Chinese, Arabic, etc into mysql database and it doesnt work, I tired to convert the xlsx file to 3 different types of csv but it loses data, also I tried to convert it to Json and still loses data. Any other ideas that I can try?

I've also tried to change the database setting to:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE mydata CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE mydata DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

but the csv file itself contains lots of _ and ? once its been converted from xslx which I assume thats a loss of data already.

Comment: Maybe your database (or database table) has a collation set that doesn't support all those languages (such as `latin1_swedish_ci`)? Try setting it to `utf8_general_ci` for example...

Comment: I've added more details to my question

Comment: Seems like the library that you use for the conversion is not Unicode-ready. Try a different (preferrably more modern) library.

Comment: I use MS excel export functionality on mac, do you have other options?